# Shell: get time and date of YYYY-MM-DDThh-mm-ss-{miliseconds}Z format

Tags: shell

I would like to get date and time of format:

```
2015-11-10T13:26:40.626Z
```

Which command should I use?

Comment: `date`, but the correct invocation depends on what version of `date` you are using. What platform are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local time

```
$ date "+%FT%T.%N %Z"
2015-11-10T10:25:27.773908528 EST
```

in UTC, removing the micro- and nanoseconds:

```
$ date --utc "+%FT%T.%N" | sed -r 's/[[:digit:]]{6}$/Z/'
2015-11-10T15:25:29.656Z
```

Comment: if anyone is interested this is exactly how VMware logs to their /var/log/esxi_install.log file.  pretty useful for making custom log entries during ESXi kickstarts

Answer (score 1):

`date +"%FT%T"` for 2015-11-10T13:26:40

but not sure, what for .626Z?

Comment: Thanks, I will append some tail. + "000Z" Server waits this format from rest request. So I don't know where it from. Probably it's some formatting from java